# What is the origin of "tablet" as in a pill?

Tags: etymology

How did we make the leap from 'writing surface' to 'pill'?

The only reference I could find was in [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tablet).

> The meaning "lozenge, pill" is first recorded 1580s.

Comment: It’s not writing surface I suspect: but the diminutive *et* (as in `cigar` -> `cigarette`) attached to the earlier word for pill, *tab*. A small(er) pill, a small tab, a *tablet*.

Comment: @DanBron Source?

Comment: @Kris Fifth and sixth words of the comment you replied to.

Comment: @DanBron: considering the the first usage of *tablet* for pill in the OED is 1425, and their first use of the [word *tab*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tab)  is around 1600, this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED seems to think it's the shape of the pills (flat and rectangular) that gave rise to the word tablet.

Their definition for this meaning of *tablet* starts

> A small, flat, or compressed piece of a solid substance, originally of rectangular form; *spec.* a measured quantity of a medicine or drug, ...

Their second citation for *tablet* meaning pill (1558) is

> Bringe it al into a masse, or lumpe, or into little tablettes, or into what fourme you will.

And from the OED, there are lots of other rectangular objects that were also called *tablets*
in the 15th through 17th centuries:

- a small slab intended to bear an inscription, drawing, or painting,
- roof or flooring tiles,
- jewelry consisting of a "flat ornament of precious metal or precious stone",
- "a flat cake of soap",
- candy made in "squares or tablets",
- a broad, square, "peece of glass".